# css3 transform width hover do not working?

Tags: html, css-transitions, css3pie

I'm trying to animate the width of the span inside the an of this link.

The same demo:   https://www.khaneyeax.com/en

```css
.lang {
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
    left: -130px;
    top: 400px;
}

.lang a {
    padding: 10px;
    color: black;
    max-width: 0;
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    transition: max-width 1s ease-in-out;
}

.lang a:hover {
    width: 300px;
    max-width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div id="left">
    <a href="" class="position-fixed three_dweb"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150"></a>
    <div class="position-fixed lang">
        <a href="" class="farsi">Language Persian FA</a>
        <a class="english">Language English EN</a>
        <a class="search"><i class="fas fa-search"></i> Advanced Search </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Seems to be working, both here and on your (nice) webpage. The search isn't available in English, only in Farsi. Mac Firefox.

Comment: It's working in the snippet here, so your problem must be in some part of the code which you didn't post.

Comment: I want to this only  Take a look at this site.  https://www.khaneyeax.com/en .